# Extra space in Spectacle screenshot

Tags: kubuntu, screenshot

I'm using Spectacle to take screenshots on Kubuntu 19.10.

If I take a screenshot with Capture Mode set to Active Window, then it takes a screenshot of the active window as expected, but the image has a lot of extra space around the edges, as in the example below. This looks very ugly on a blog because of the amount of wasted space.

[image]

Is there any way to remove this extra space and just get the window in the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Breeze for your window decorations,

Open *System Settings > Application Style > Window Decorations*

Hover over your selected Window Decorations theme. Click on the *Settings* icon that appears in the lower right corner.

In the window that opens, click the *Shadow* tab, and set *Size* to *None*.

[image: Shadowless image]

(Note: this may not be available in other non-Breeze themes.)

---

There's an open issue here: [Option to omit shadow and transparent border from windows in Active Window and Window Under Cursor modes](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=372408).

Comment: Is it possible to keep the shadow, but just remove it in screenshots? I figured it might be a setting in Spectacle, but now I seem to understand that it takes whatever the desktop theme is rendering.

Comment: I don't know about that. I don't see a such a setting or option only for Spectacle.

Comment: Actually I think it's quite acceptable to set the shadow to Small instead of Large.

Comment: I've just turned it off altogether. The issue of having a Spectacle-specific option has been heatedly raised in the past. If you're interested, I can dig up the link.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Plasma 6.0, Spectacle now has the option to exclude the shadows.

https://invent.kde.org/plasma/kwin/-/merge_requests/4499
https://invent.kde.org/graphics/spectacle/-/merge_requests/272